# Event over appending data doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, append

The event after appending data doesn't work. I've tried width "on", "live" and "delegate" but I got the same wrong results.

I've simplified my code to expose to you what I mean:

```
<html>
    <ul id="list-1">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list-2">
    </ul>
</html>
```

And my jQuery example:

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('#list-1 li'), function() {
        $('#list-2').append('<li>Some text</li>');
    });
    $('#list-2 li').click(function() {
        alert('This event doesn\'t work');
    });
});
```

Comment: BTW: `alert('This event doesn\'t work');` (escape!) - so yeah, BTW2 it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/L7x3hf90/ and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7x3hf90/1/)

Comment: Make sure you included the jQuery library... or open Developer console and read out loud the errors